# Secure contents of file uploaded using flask

Tags: python, file, flask

I am new to web development and trying to build a website using Flask which asks a user to upload a file, processes it and gives some statistics related to the contents. I am planning to deploy this on heroku(free version). **I wanted to make sure the contents of the file are secured**. Currently I am deleting the file uploaded and closing file handler after reading the contents.
What I have so far:

```
    class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
        file = FileField()

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def upload():
            form = UploadForm()
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                filename = secure_filename(form.file.data.filename)
                session['filename'] = filename
                form.file.data.save(filename)
                return redirect(url_for('stats'))
        
            return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
    @app.route('/stats', methods=['GET'])
        def stats():
            try:
                file_handle = open(session['filename'], encoding="utf8", mode="r")
                file_contents = file_handle.read()
                #processing done in this method
                data = prepare_stats(file_contents)
                 
                #to delete the uploaded file
                @after_this_request
                def remove_file(response):
                    try:
                        file_handle.close()
                        os.remove(session['filename'])
                    except Exception as error:
                        app.logger.error(
                            "Error removing or closing downloaded file handle", error)
                    return response
                return render_template("stats.html", data)
            except Exception:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Is there any scope to improve this further in order to avoid the contents of file being exposed?

Comment: If you are just reading the contents of the file as a string there is no danger regardless of what type of file gets uploaded, unless you use `exec` or there is a 0 day exploit. The danger is when the user is able to save the file on your server and then accesses it directly via the the file's URL. For example, if someone uploads a ```.py``` file with a shell in place of an image, the attacker can then execute the file by navigating to the URL. You can always filter for extensions and assign the file a random unique name and extension to further protect against rce.

Comment: @saratur thanks for the input. I have limited the file extensions allowed using app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']. I am restricting the size as well by defining MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH. My question was more towards avoiding the contents of file being exposed